# Dynamic menus from database in laravel using lavary/laravel-menu

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a laravel application with static menus. 
Now I want to change this into dynamic menus from the database. 
So far so good so I made a migration for a table called menu_items.

Then I wrote a middleware with following handle method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    \Menu::make('mainmenu', function ($menu) {

        $items = MenuItem::all();

        foreach ($items as $item) {

            if ($item->parent_id == null) {

                $menu->add($item->title, $item->link)
                    ->prepend('<i class="'.$item->icon.'"></i>');    
            }
            else {
                // dd($menu);
                $parent = $item->parent_id - 1;
                $menu->find($parent)->add($item->title, $item->link);
            }
        }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I changed to lavary/laravel-menu and try to get submenus added to the parent menu item dynamically. I do not understand why laravel always tells me at

```
$menu->find($parent)->add($item->title, $item->link);
```

Call to a member function add() on null $parent is not null if I print out with dd() If I do something like `$menu->last()->add($item->title, $item->link);` It works but thats not what I want...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to write function in your controller, and return variable to template? How will you access {{ Menu::main() }}?

```
$menu = Menu::build($menu_items, function ($menu, $menu_item) {
        $menu->link($menu_item->title, $menu_item->link);
```

{{ $menu->whatDoYouNeedToAccess }}